# Intersection between a closed set and $y=x$ on $[0,1]$

Tags: functions

I was given a little variant of "show that a surjective continueous function from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ intersects with $y=x$ at least once"

Let $P$ be a closed set of $[0,1]^2$ such that $\forall x\in[0,1]$, the **interval** $\{y\in[0,1]\mid(x,y)\in P\}\neq\emptyset$. Show that $P$ intersects with $y=x$.

How would one prove that ?

Comment: @math137 I know the answer to the first version :) I'm looking for an answer of the variant

Answer (score 4):

This is false: consider the set $P = \{(x,1) | 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2} \} \cup \{(x,0) | \frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq 1 \}$.

It's possibly true if you insist that $P$ is connected?

Comment: You're right, sorry. I believe it must be a _compact_ and not _closed_ set then.

Comment: @user176015 Compact sets may be connected or not connected.

Comment: @Did Sorry, that was a wrong edit. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately compact is the same as closed here (compact = closed and bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and everybody is living in the bounded unit square)- connected is really the condition you want.

If you were connected, note that the complement of the diagonal is two connected blobs $(x > y)$ and $(x < y)$, so $P$ would land in one of them. But then it will have empty fibre over $x =  0 or 1.$